# jquery-ui not applying css

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a jquery slider, but jquery-ui css is not being applied to a div at all. Any help will be appreciated!

```
var dummy = document.createElement('div')
dummy.innerHTML = 'dummy'

var wRange = document.createElement('div')
wRange.setAttribute('id', 'range')
wRange.classList.add('cntr')

$("#range").slider({
  range: "min",
  min: 0,
  max: 999,
  value: 50,
  slide: function(e, ui) {
    return $(".ui-slider-handle").html(ui.value)
  }
})

$(".ui-slider-handle").html("50")

document.body.appendChild(dummy)
document.body.appendChild(wRange)
```

Here is : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6src0wf/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting elements

```
$("#range")slider({...});
$(".ui-slider-handle").html("50");
```

before they appended to body, so jQuery can't find them in a DOM.

Do that:

```
document.body.appendChild(dummy)
document.body.appendChild(wRange)

$("#range").slider({
  range: "min",
  min: 0,
  max: 999,
  value: 50,
  slide: function(e, ui) {
    return $(".ui-slider-handle").html(ui.value)
  }
})

$(".ui-slider-handle").html("50")
```

Or jQuery style way:

```
var dummy = $('<div>').html('dummy');

var wRange = $('<div>')
    .attr('id','range')
    .addClass('cntr')
    .slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 999,
        value: 50,
        slide: function(e, ui) {
            return $(".ui-slider-handle").html(ui.value)
        }
    });

$(document.body).append(dummy, wRange);
```